# Como adicionar legenda fixa flutuando no meio do gráfico?

Tags: javascript, google, google-charts

Preciso adicionar duas legendas no meio do gráfico, elas são apenas informativas mas precisam ficam no meio dele. Tentei varias formas e ainda não consegui adicionar.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'x');
        data.addColumn('number', 'values');
        data.addColumn({id:'i0', type:'number', role:'interval'});
        data.addColumn({id:'i1', type:'number', role:'interval'});
        data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
        data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
        data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});
        data.addColumn({id:'i2', type:'number', role:'interval'});

        data.addRows([
            [1, 100, 90, 110, 85, 96, 104, 120],
            [2, 120, 95, 130, 90, 113, 124, 140],
            [3, 130, 105, 140, 100, 117, 133, 139],
            [8, 100, 90, 110, 85, 95, 102, 110]]);

        // The intervals data as narrow lines (useful for showing raw source data)
        var options_lines = {
            title: 'Line intervals, default',
            curveType: 'function',
            lineWidth: 4,
            intervals: { 'style':'line' },
            legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart_lines = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_lines'));
        chart_lines.draw(data, options_lines);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_lines" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Coloque seu código na pergunta.

Comment: coloquei o código

Comment: Olá, no meio do gráfico não consegui, somente acima veja como ficou no link [ https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Gp3011Fiv7 ], porém segue link da API para você verificar se encontra. [ https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#configuration-options ]